# Consolidating factor categories from one column into a new column

Tags: r

This is my first time posting a question. I am pretty new to R. I was searching for the answer for quite some time and did not find an answer. So here goes. I have a very large data set (over 140K obs), one column contains categories for a "programtype", the options are:

- Federal Agency
- Federal Agency/University
- National Survey Program
- LTER
- University
- Non-Profit Agency
- State Agency
- State Agency/Citizen Monitoring Program
- State Agency/University/Citizen Monitoring Program
- Tribal Agency

What I want to do is create a new column where I consolidate some of the categories together. I would like:

- [Federal Agency, Federal Agency/University, National Survey Program] ***converted to*** Federal Agency/University
- [LTER, University] ***converted to*** LTER/University
- [Non-Profit Agency] ***converted to*** Non-Profit Agency
- [State Agency] ***converted to*** State Agency
- [State Agency/Citizen Monitoring Program, State Agency/University/Citizen Monitoring Program] ***converted to*** Citizen Science Monitoring Program
- [Tribal Agency] ***converted to*** Tribal Agency

Some of them will stay the same. I have tried ifelse statements, but it seems to have a hard time determining what is in the original column and returns NAs for numerous observations. I checked all my spelling so that is not it. This is what I tried based on another answer somewhere on here. The name of my dataset is TP_state, on of the other columns is lagoslakeid. However, it's not working properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
x <- c(TP_state$programtype) 
y <- c(TP_state$lagoslakeid)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, Program_Type := ifelse(x %in% c("Federal Agency", "Federal Agency/University", "National Survey Program"), "Federal Agency/University",
                 ifelse(x %in% c("LTER", "University"), "LTER/University",
                 ifelse(x %in% c("Non-Profit Agency"), "Non-Profit Agency",       
                 ifelse(x %in% c("State Agency"), "State Agency",
                 ifelse(x %in% c("State Agency/University/Citizen Monitoring Program", "State Agency/Citizen Monitoring Program"), "Citizen Monitoring Program", 
                 ifelse(x %in% c("Tribal Agency"), "Tribal Agency", NA))))))]
```

Comment: See `fct_collapse` from the `forcats` package.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. Please tell me if it works for you!

```
for(i in 1:length(df$column_with_factors)){
  if(grepl(pattern = 'federal agency|national survey program', x = df$column[i], ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'Federal Agency/University'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = '^lter$|^university$', x = df$column[i], ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'LTER/University'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = 'non-profit agency', x = df$column[i], ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'Non-profit Agency'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = '^state agency$', x = df$column[i], ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'State Agency'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = 'state agency/(citizen monitoring program|university/citizen monitoring program)', x = df$column[i], ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'Citizen Science Monitoring Program'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = 'tribal agency', x = df$column[i], ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'Tribal Agency'
  } else x <- NA
}

df$column_with_factors <- as.factor(df$column_with_factors)
```

But this will run faster:

```
df$column_with_factors <- sapply(df$column_with_factors, function(x){
  if(grepl(pattern = 'federal agency|national survey program', x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'Federal Agency/University'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = '^lter$|^university$', x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'LTER/University'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = 'non-profit agency', x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'Non-profit Agency'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = '^state agency$', x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'State Agency'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = 'state agency/(citizen monitoring program|university/citizen monitoring program)', x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'Citizen Science Monitoring Program'
  } else if(grepl(pattern = 'tribal agency', x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)){
    x <- 'Tribal Agency'
  } else x <- NA
})

df$column_with_factors <- as.factor(df$column_with_factors)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `forcats` package is excellent at recoding tasks like this.

First create some demo data...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

df <-
  tibble(
    programtype = c(
      "Federal Agency",
      "Federal Agency",
      "Federal Agency",
      "State Agency/University/Citizen Monitoring",
      "State Agency/University/Citizen Monitoring Program",
      "Federal Agency/University",
      "National Survey Program",
      "LTER",
      "University",
      "Non-Profit Agency",
      "Non-Profit Agency",
      "Non-Profit Agency",
      "Non-Profit Agency",
      "Non-Profit Agency",
      "State Agency",
      "State Agency",
      "State Agency/Citizen Monitoring Program",
      "State Agency/University/Citizen Monitoring Program",
      "Tribal Agency",
      "Tribal Agency",
      "Tribal Agency"
    ),
    ID = 1:21
  )
```

Then use `fct_recode` to replace values...

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    new_categories = fct_recode(
      programtype,
      "Federal Agency/University" = "Federal Agency",
      "Federal Agency/University" = "Federal Agency/University",
      "Federal Agency/University" = "National Survey Program",
      "LTER/University" = "LTER",
      "LTER/University" = "University",
      "Citizen Science Monitoring Program" = "State Agency/Citizen Monitoring Program",
      "Citizen Science Monitoring Program" = "State Agency/University/Citizen Monitoring"
    )
  )
```